# multiple rows subfigure

Tags: subfloats

I want to have a following layout of pictures:
[image]

I'm using subfigures:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\newcommand{\fakeimage}{{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\fbox{\rule{0pt}{3cm}\hspace{4cm}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \fakeimage
        \caption{Image}\label{fig:image1}
    \end{subfigure} %

    \hfill

    \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
        %\centering
        \fakeimage
        \caption{Image}\label{fig:image12}
    \end{subfigure}

    \hfill

    \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \fakeimage
        \caption{Image}\label{fig:image12}
    \end{subfigure}

    \hfill

    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \fakeimage
        \caption{Image}\label{fig:image3}
    \end{subfigure}

    \RawCaption{\caption{General caption}
    \label{fig:images}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: Eliminate the blank lines between subfigures 1, 2, and 3. Remember: In TeX and LaTeX, a blank line (in text mode) generates a line break.

Comment: @Mico, I'm really sorry - repost your answer, and I'll ask DomDom to unaccept mine and accept yours. Then I'll delete mine.

Comment: @heather - Not to worry!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Mico said, eliminate the blank lines. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}   
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor} 
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\newcommand{\fakeimage}{{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\fbox{\rule{0pt}{3cm}\hspace{4cm}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \fakeimage
    \caption{Image}\label{fig:image1}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \fakeimage
    \caption{Image}\label{fig:image12}
\end{subfigure}
   \hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \fakeimage
    \caption{Image}\label{fig:image13}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \fakeimage
  \caption{Image}\label{fig:image3}
\end{subfigure} 
\RawCaption{\caption{General caption}
\label{fig:images}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Thanks to Mico for the solution (see comments)!

Comment: +1. You may want to add a `\bigskip` directive ahead of the fourth subfigure.

Comment: @Mico: thank you. I have done so and compiled it; however, there is no noticeable difference.

Comment: Remove the final `\hfill`, insert a blank line, and insert `\bigskip` *after* the blank line (and before the final `subfigure`).

Comment: @Mico: ah. Looks much better. I'll update the answer.