# Multiple figures per row with vertical label

Tags: floats

I want to do something similar to what is done in [this](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/publications/papers/philbin07.pdf) paper:

[image]

In particular I'm interested in:

1. Same amount of images per row
2. Using a vertical label to categorize each row
3. Adding a caption
4. Wrapping the image (so there can be text on one side)

I've read some questions ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324258/multiple-rows-subfigure) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10245/how-to-order-3-images-horizontally)) but they are very different from what I want, can you help me?

I've tried this, but I'm getting errors:

```
\usepackage{subcaption} % for subfigures

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{Figures/all_souls_000021.jpg}&
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{Figures/all_souls_000091.jpg}&
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{Figures/oxford_000177.jpg}\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{A table with figures}
\label{tab:mytable}
\end{table}
```

Error:

```
! Missing } inserted.<inserted text>} ...olumnwidth]{Figures/all_souls_000021.jpg}&
```

Comment: organize your images in table. in the first column you put your text (rotated), in other your images.

Comment: @Zarko I've tried your approach but I'm getting errors, could you give a look at my updated question?

Comment: pleas help us to help you!extend your code snippet to complete small (Minimal (non)Working Example: MWE) document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` and load in preamble only necessary packages. It is not fun to recreate your document from scratch ...

Comment: What do you mean with `wrapping the image`?

Comment: @Bernard I mean like `wrapfigure`, where the "table of images" can be surrounded by text.

Answer (score 8):

With a handy interface:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xparse,booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{places}{mm}
 {% #1 is the desired width, #2 is the number of photos per line
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % no space between rows
  \dim_set:Nn \l_places_width_dim
   {
    (#1-\ht\strutbox-\dp\strutbox-2pt)/(#2)
   }
  \begin{tabular}{r @{\hspace{2pt}} *{#2}{c}}
 }
 {
  \end{tabular}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\place}{mm}
 {% #1 is the name of the place, #2 is the comma separated list of images
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_places_images_in_seq { #2 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_places_images_out_seq \l_places_images_in_seq { \places_set_image:n {##1} }
  \seq_put_left:Nn \l_places_images_out_seq
   {
    \begin{tabular}{c}\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\strut#1}\end{tabular}
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_places_images_out_seq { & } \\ \addlinespace
 }

\dim_new:N \l_places_width_dim
\seq_new:N \l_places_images_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l_places_images_out_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \places_set_image:n
 {
  \makebox[\l_places_width_dim]
   {
    \begin{tabular}{c}
    \includegraphics[
      width=\l_places_width_dim,
      height=\l_places_width_dim,
      keepaspectratio,
    ]{#1}
    \end{tabular}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{places}{\textwidth}{5}
\place{Hertford}{
  example-image,
  example-image-a,
  example-image-b,
  example-image-a,
  example-image-b
}
\place{Pitt Rivers}{
  example-image,
  example-image-9x16,
  example-image-b,
  example-image-a,
  example-image-b
}
\end{places}

\caption{Images}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{places}{.5\textwidth}{5}
\place{Hertford}{
  example-image,
  example-image-a,
  example-image-b,
  example-image-a,
  example-image-b
}
\place{Pitt Rivers}{
  example-image,
  example-image-9x16,
  example-image-b,
  example-image-a,
  example-image-b
}
\end{places}

\caption{Images}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: any chance I can add a header for each column? For instance like in the image here
[link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356468/how-to-vertically-align-a-text-in-a-landscape-table-with-images?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 6):

I suspect, that you like to have something like this:

[image]

but I'm not sure. The code snippet of above figure is:

```
    \begin{figure}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{Radcliffe Cam}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l XXX }
\rothead{text 1}        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{image-1}
                        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{image-2}    
                        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{image-3}     \\  \addlinespace[2pt]
\rothead{Radcliffe Cam} &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{image-4}
                        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{image-5}
                        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{image-6}
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{A table with figures}
\label{tab:mytable}
    \end{figure}
```

In preamble of your document should be loaded (among others) the following packages:

```
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
```

**Addendum:**
In the cases when you like to have images in "block" narrower then text width, than you need to prescribe narrower width of `tabularx` (not of figure environment, this you can't do on the way as you show in comment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo,   % in real document remove "demo" 
            export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{Radcliffe Cam}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\hsize}
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\linewidth}{l XXX }% <-- here is determined table width
\rothead{\centering
         text 1}        &   \includegraphics[valign=m]{image-1}
                        &   \includegraphics[valign=m]{image-2}    
                        &   \includegraphics[valign=m]{image-3}     \\  
    \addlinespace[2pt]
\rothead{Radcliffe Cam} &   \includegraphics[valign=m]{image-4}
                        &   \includegraphics[valign=m]{image-5}
                        &   \includegraphics[valign=m]{image-6}
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{A table with figures}
\label{tab:mytable}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
After two and half years ... :-) the code fragment in the addendum is extended to complete MWE. Also some small improvements are done. Now MWE should be simple testable.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very nice and simple solution. However, what if I want that this table doesn't take more than 80% text width? I tried with `\begin{figure}{0.8\textwidth}` but I'm getting `! Missing number, treated as zero.<to be read again>} \begin{figure}{0.8\textwidth}`

Comment: @user6321, than you declare narrower width of table. See addendum to may answer above.