# Group subfigures with vertical and horizontal labels in Latex

Tags: graphics

How can I group a set of figures like in the image? I found some example with vertical labels (Type 1, Type 2, Type 3), but I also need to include head (horizontal) labels (Type A, ...). How do I refer to any of the sub-figures in the text?

[image]

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377537/4427

Comment: @egreg, this question seems to be duplicate to this question ...